# Why I paste the string into the bash command line in the putty window I always get a wave mark at the head of the string?

Tags: putty

I use the Windows as my main `os`, and the putty link to a `Ubuntu`. When I copy a string in Windows and paste into the putty bash command line I always get a `wave mark` at the head of the string. Why's that? 
But if I paste the same string when I enter `vim` in the putty, the string shows fine without the `wave mark`. How to fix it?

I haven't got 10 reputations what means that I can't post a pic. The link below is the img file url. you will find that at the head of the string I get a `~`

[image: This is what is shown on my pc]

-- update ---
I change the shell back to `bash` but the question still there.

[1214122640.bmp](http://7xpvdr.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/1214122640.bmp)

Comment: The screenshot also suggests that the Ubuntu system you're using gives you `zsh` shell, so it might be the cause , but I might be wrong. Try entering a different shell, for example `sh` and then pasting. If the same thing occurs, that's probably `putty` issue. Oh, and if you see something like `^[O^[OD^[OC` when using `/bin/sh` , don't freak out - it's normal

Comment: @Serg Ialready change the default shell to `bash` but it seems no use.